# @Value annotation not resolved in a class that belongs to dependency jar

Tags: java, spring, web, annotations

I have a simple web-app that includes a dependency jar for some functionality and needs to use a property value defined in main app code.

Thanks in advance to help me out on this.

---

**dependency.jar contains**

```
public class MyClass {

    @Value("${abc.def}")
    private String abc;  // DOES NOT GET RESOLVED. IS ALWAYS NULL

}
```

### dependency-context.xml

my-app.war contains

```
public class LocalClass {

    @Value("${abc.def}")
    private String abc;  // GETS RESOLVED TO CORRECT PROPERTY VALUE
}
```

context.xml
    imports dependency-context.xml

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into this [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9989).  It makes it very difficult to use the @Value with multiple PropertyPlaceholderConfigurers from different projects using import context.  To solve this problem try to autowire the existing PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer into your bean configuration method (assuming you can use @Configuration) and update the object in the method with the values from your project.

Answer (score 0):

@scottmf is on the right lines, but you can't read properties directly from PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer :(

Instead, I created a String @Bean in the war...

```
<bean id="myProperty" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="ABC"/>
</bean>
```

which can be @Autowired into the jar class:

```
@Bean
public Object myBean(String myProperty) { ... }
```